# EWS API - Save Email to file system without using Third Party DLL's

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I need to save the Email Message on the disk as an .msg file, for this I am using EWS API. I am sucessfully able to save the FileAttachment but not ItemAttachment.

Is there any sample code available which I can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange only deals with EML (MIME) format. To get the attachments you need to handle the various MIME part formats which 3rd party libraries do for you (*e.g. deal directly with the MIME content*). You also need to consider how you handle embedded EML items in the source EML.

Comment: So the best I can do is to use some third party library. Is there any freely available library you can refer to.

Comment: @AnkushGupta - for a free solution, try this CodeProject solution. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/reading_an_outlook_msg.aspx